# How to display CSV data but stopping at a blank row

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tree, treeview

I'm trying to import a csv into a simple tree. The csv file has 3 columns, and if one if one row in a column has data then the other two also do. What I'm having issues with is how do I read in the csv file data for a particular item but stop when I hit a blank row - which indicates the end of the data and the start of the next item - note the populated rows varys length.

```
with open("c:\python\projects\somedwgs.csv") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for col in reader:
            result=(col['Product'])
            if self.SOentry.get() == result:
                    descr=(col['PartDesc'])
                    descDwg=(col['Drawings'])
                    descIss=(col['Issues'])
                    descDscr=(col['Documents'])
                    while True:
                        if row['PartDesc'] != "":
                            self.dwgtree.insert("",'end',values=(descDwg,descIss,descDscr))
                            next(reader)
                            break
```

This partially works, the first row inserts the values correctly, but I cant get it to insert the next row and then the next row etc etc. For reference it needs keep inserting rows until the 'PartsDesc' field in my csv file is blank - which indicates the end of that particular range of data

Comment: put `if not col: break` somewhere.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm completely lost here - despite trying your suggestion. I've rewritten things but I can only get the first row to print into my widget where I actually want it to keep printing rows until the PartDesc field is blank. I'm missing something very simple I'm sure